# Retrieve id of each INSERT statement in multi query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to retrieve id (ua_id is in my case) for each INSERT statement in following SQL request

```
INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,3);
```

using `mysqli::multi_query()` to execute it wheres ua_id is AUTO_INCREMENT primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. you do a multiquery, let's use it:

```
<?php
$db->multi_query('
INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,2);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,3);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()') or trigger_error($db->error);
do {
   if ($result = $db->store_result()) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
          var_dump($row);
      }
   }
} while ($db->next_result());
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you can use **LAST_INSERT_ID()** function. You need to use this function each time - after INSERT statement. It gets ID for the last inserted record.

MySQL documentation - [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: It tends to return only id from last INSERT statement, but not all of them. Also `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_insert_id[1,2,..,n]` after each INSERT doesn't work too.

Comment: This function returns last ID for auto-incremented values. It must be executed in current session - where INSERT statement was called.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code because if i form it like this: `INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,1);
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
            INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,2);
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` it doesn't seems to work as expected.

Comment: I have added a link. There is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean lastInsertId?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

mysqli->insert_id will return the ID of the first row inserted if you insert in the same table you then know that the next row inserted is the first row insert_id + 1...

If you work with many tables at once you then need to scroll back your results then you need to create another query using :

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table-a WHERE 1
...
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table-n WHERE 1
```

Now I don't know what is better (single insert query or multi query)...

Comment: This is probably not good - What if another user was inserting at the same time as you?  What if a transaction was rolled back (in which case there could be a gap in the sequence)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `$mysqli->insert_id` - see working example below.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, user, pass, db);

$query  = "INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,1); ";
$query .= "INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,2); ";
$query .= "INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES (1,3); ";

if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* Returns the auto generated id used in the last query */
        printf("%d\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
        /* Check if loop should continue */
        if ($mysqli->more_results() === FALSE) break;
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

Use built in mysqli::$insert_id - documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php