# Store query into json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have 3 queries which are running consecutively, I want to store `Case_ID` to

`$json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=> )) . "]";`

So that I can store it in HTML via localstorage. How do I achieve this?

**PHP**

```
$query = "insert into `Case`(`informant_userid`,`CaseName`,`CaseTime`) values ('" . $informant_userid . "','" . $CaseName . "',now());";
$query.= "insert into Picture (Case_Pic,Case_ID) values ('" .addslashes($imagefile). "', LAST_INSERT_ID());" ;    
$query.= "SELECT `Case_ID` from `Case` ORDER BY `Case_ID` DESC LIMIT 1 ";

Echo($query);
$result = $conn->multi_query($query);

$count = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>$count[0])) . "]";


if (!$result){
    $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>0)) . "]";        
}
else {
    $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=> )) . "]";        
}

echo $json_out;
```

Comment: What does 'I want to store Case_ID to $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=> )) . "]";' mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13849004/4248328   . get all id first and then encode it

Comment: @Anant I would like to retrieve the result for the third query only. Not all the queries.