# Is it possible to use LAST_INSERT_ID() in php for-loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli-multi-query

Is is possible use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in php for-loop. I need to get the last `playground` PK as a FK in `guardian` table. Both needs to insert at a same time. Pardon me for not using `PDO`, i just want to get this thing to work first.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO playground (parent, children, amount) VALUES ('John','susy','2000');";

$levelarray = array ("One", "Two", "Three");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($levelarray); $i++) {
    $level = $levelarray[$i];
    $query .= "INSERT INTO guardian (playgroundid, level) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$level');";
}
mysqli_multi_query($con, $query);
```

I have also tried this. But the one below outputs the last id, but not the newly inserted id.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO playground (parent, children, amount) VALUES ('John','Susy','2000');";

$sql = "SELECT playground_id AS playgroundid FROM playground ORDER BY playground_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$playId = $row['playgroundid'];

$levelarray = array ("One", "Two", "Three");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($levelarray); $i++) {
    $level = $levelarray[$i];
    $query .= "INSERT INTO guardian (playgroundid, level) VALUES ('$playId','$level');";
}
mysqli_multi_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: @TommyBs sorry for the typo, When i entered here i missed it, but the code column name was alright.

Comment: Why don't you try that and see what happens?

Comment: do like this:- `$query = "INSERT INTO playground (parent, children, amount) VALUES ('John','susy','2000');";
if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
 $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);


 $levelarray = array ("One", "Two", "Three");
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($levelarray); $i++) {
  $level = $levelarray[$i];
  $query = "INSERT INTO guardian (playgroundid, level) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$level');";
  mysqli_query($con,$query)
 }
}`

Comment: May this is useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849004/2893413

Comment: @AlivetoDie - Post it as an answer...

Comment: FYI, lines 4 and 5 can be written much easier as foreach ($levelarray as $level) {

Comment: Using prepared statements and bind variables will make your code more secure and you can prepare the insert once and execute it with the individual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the last inserted id using [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

And then use it to the next query like below:-

```
$query = "INSERT INTO playground (parent, children, amount) VALUES ('John','susy','2000');"; 

if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){ 
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);  //get last inserted id
    $levelarray = array ("One", "Two", "Three"); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($levelarray); $i++) { 
        $level = $levelarray[$i]; 
        $query = "INSERT INTO guardian (playgroundid, level) VALUES ($id,'$level');"; 
        mysqli_query($con,$query) ;
    } 
}
```

***Or you can still use `mysqli_multi_query()` like below:-***

```
$query = "INSERT INTO playground (parent, children, amount) VALUES ('John','susy','2000');"; 

if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){ 
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);  //get last inserted id
    $query1 = '';
    $levelarray = array ("One", "Two", "Three"); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($levelarray); $i++) { 
        $level = $levelarray[$i]; 
        $query1 .= "INSERT INTO guardian (playgroundid, level) VALUES ($id,'$level');"; 
    } 
     mysqli_multi_query($con, $query1);
}
```

Note:- Your query is wide open for `SQL INJECTION`. so try to use `prepared statement` to prevent from it.

Comment: Is it `=` or `.=`

Comment: it is `=`. query executed inside loop

Comment: @TheHive  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Hey! Is it possible to use it from database like `$_POST['levels]`

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't work. The first guardian will get the id of the playground, and the next two will get the id of the previous guardian.

Use `mysqli_insert_id()` instead to get the id and save it as a variable outside of the for loop.

Comment: yes you are right, the id was mixed up when inserting three rows.